# Cannot drop table SQL Error: ORA-00600

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I edited a table in SQL Developer, changing its identity column to start with 0. Upon pressing ok, I can no longer make an changes the identity column and I cannot even drop the table because of this. I get the error message:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12811], [92006], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
```

Putting 0 for start with for the identity column always causes this.

How can I remove this table?

EDIT: 
so this is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
ALTER TABLE T1 MODIFY ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY; --fine
ALTER TABLE T1 MODIFY ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 0; --SQL Error: ORA-00600     and you can no longer drop table or alter column
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Oracle says you should contact them in the event of a 600 error: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600 I'm curious now.

Comment: Looks possibly related to bug 18744247; but yes, you need to contact Oracle and raise a service request (assuming you have a support contract, of course). It would still be interesting to see the commands used to create, modify and drop though - if only to know what to avoid.

Comment: It's just debugging, but what happens when you set other values than zero ? Especially : 1 (one) ? What if you create ANOTHER table, and try to do the same (first with value 1, then try with zero). What is your exact DB version (5 digit) ?

Comment: DB version is 12.1.0.2.0 Enterprise Edition. And if you start it as 1 first and then 0: SQL Error: ORA-04006: START WITH cannot be less than MINVALUE
04006. 00000 -  "START WITH cannot be less than MINVALUE" then executing with 0 again gives SQL Error: ORA-00600.

Comment: I don't see in your DDL where you are declaring a `MINVALUE`. As per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm) if you do not specify a `MINVALUE` it will default to `NOMINVALUE` which is 1.

Comment: I would prefer using sequences instead of the identity.  It is easier to reset the sequence or determine the current value. Oracle added the identity to match the SQL Server identity (which is terrible, IMHO).  In 12c, you can add it as a sequence. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53asktom-1999186.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering this issue occasionally likely because of frequent `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY identity_column GENERATED BY ...` statements(due to my needs). I workaround this by renaming the original table(it works well), creating a new one(with a proper name) and moving all the data into the new one.